# Combine standard error in finite difference with Monte Carlo

Tags: black-scholes, monte-carlo, greeks, standard-deviation, finite-difference

I'm using Montecarlo to estimate the value of an option,

$$\overline V(S_T, r, \sigma, T;N)=\mathbb{E} \left[V(S_T, r, \sigma, T)\right]$$
which comes with a standard error $SE$.

I'm using "bump-and-reval" (finite differences) to compute the greeks. So for example for Delta:

$$
\Delta \approx \frac{\overline V(S_T+\Delta S, r, \sigma, T;N)-\overline V(S_T-\Delta S, r, \sigma, T;N)}{2\Delta S}
$$

my question is, what's the right way to combine the standard errors to get the right one for $\Delta$?

What about for a second order greek, like Gamma:

$$
\Gamma \approx \frac{\overline V(S_T+\Delta S, r, \sigma, T;N)-2\overline V(S_T, r, \sigma, T;N)+\overline V(S_T-\Delta S, r, \sigma, T;N)}{(\Delta S)^2}
$$